# Execute event starts later each time its executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I have multiple buttons which each fires an `onClick` event.
My project is developed in React.

When I fire the onClick event several times, it slows down the start of the event each time it is fired.
When it's starts to get slow I see that each time the onClick event is executes twice.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?
I thougt it was because of the `setTimeout` function, but without the setTimeout is still slows down.

Here's a runnable example:

```js
const Button = props => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClickHandler}>{props.text}</button>
  );
}

const Box = props => {
  function closeBox(e) {
    setTimeout(() => (
      props.onClose()
    ), 400);
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={(e) => closeBox(e)}>{props.text}</div>
  );
}

const Main = () => {
  const [event1, setEvent1] = React.useState(false);
  const [event2, setEvent2] = React.useState(false);
  const [event3, setEvent3] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button text="Event 1" onClickHandler={() => setEvent1(true)} />
      <Button text="Event 2" onClickHandler={() => setEvent2(true)} />
      <Button text="Event 3" onClickHandler={() => setEvent3(true)} />
      {event1 &&
        <Box text="Box 1" onClose={() => setEvent1(false)} />
      }
      {event2 &&
        <Box text="Box 2" onClose={() => setEvent2(false)} />
      }
      {event3 &&
        <Box text="Box 3" onClose={() => setEvent3(false)} />
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I moved your code blocks into a runnable Stack Snippet ([details here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/)). When I ran it, I got an error because `props` was undefined, which was because both `Button` and `Box` were incorrect -- they weren't accepting the `props` parameter. I fixed that, but...is it also wrong in your real code?

Comment: I can't replicate the behavior you describe with the runnable example.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't want to post my real code. So I simulated my code. The structure is the same. But Thanks ;)

Comment: That's fine (indeed, it's for the best), but it has to be a [mcve]. Right now, it isn't verifiable. The example doesn't do what you describe (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see it's working perfectly in the snippet. I'm trying to find out what it could be. Cus ectually there is vinous difference.